# What is wrong with my eeprom?

Tags: i2c, eeprom

I am using an eeprom [M24C32-W](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24c32-w.pdf) from ST.
Here is my schematic with VCC=3.3V. The <s>write protection</s> Write Control pin is connected to VSS and thus should be disabled. The address of the device is 0xA0 (or 0x50<<1) because the pins E1, E2, E3 are connected to VSS.
[image: schematic]

And here is my write and read command: I want to write value 0xAA to address 0xF0 but I cannot manage to read back this value. This is what my logic analyzer measures at the pull-up resistors.
[image: write (top), read (bottom)]

Here is what I have tried so far:

- writing to and reading from different memory addresses: 0x0000, 0x00F0, 0x00FF, 0x0FFF, 0xFFFF,
- different delays between write and read: 0ms (it failed), 10ms, 1000ms.
- write to device, power down board, power up board, read from device.

None of those worked so far, I am running out of ideas.

EDIT: I have tried various clock speeds with no success: 100kHz, 10kHz, 1kHz.
The EEPROM is the only device on the I2C bus.

---

#### Solved:

It was simply a faulty hardware problem. I switched the eeprom for a new one and now it works. Thank you all.

Comment: Where are you measuring? Note that 3.3kΩ might not be the optimal pull-up for your application. Try with a much lower SCL frequency.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following frequencies: 10kHz (the one in the picture), 100kHz and 1kHz. I am going to try changing the value of the pull-up resistors.

Comment: I am measuring on the pull-up resistors.

Comment: Logic analysers can fool you as they simply show if you went through a particular voltage; try looking at the signals with a scope.

Comment: When you read from address 0x0000 what value do you read back? Still 0xF7?

Comment: I read 0xFF everywhere but some addresses. According to the datasheet, I should read 0xFF everywhere when the eeprom is new. I am going to replace it with another one to see if it makes any difference. Thank you.

Comment: It was simply a faulty hardware problem. I switched the eeprom for a new one and now it works. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You say it's a *write protection* pin, implying that asserting it prevents writes.  Note that the pin name is written with a bar over it in the schematic.  That means negative logic.  Tying it low therefore asserts its function.  If it is truly a write *protect* pin, then you are preventing writes by tying it low.

Since you didn't provide a link to the datasheet, I'll leave it to you to check what the function and polarity of the pin really are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The [datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/m24c32-w.pdf) says: "If
the addressed location is Write-protected, by Write Control (WC) being driven high, the device replies with NoAck, and the location is not modified. If, instead, the addressed location is not Write-protected, the device replies with Ack." The device replies with ACK (see the screenshots of the logic analyzer), therefore the location should have been modified.
Sorry for not providing a link, I have not enough reputation to add another link to my question.